# how to login via gmail in php 5.3 sdk

Tags: php, gmail

I'm developing gmail login in my app. but I don't know what I've to do to cope with it. where do I set `app_id`, `credential` and ...
any help?

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';

define('APPLICATION_NAME', 'Gmail API PHP Quickstart');
define('CREDENTIALS_PATH', '~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json');
define('CLIENT_SECRET_PATH', __DIR__ . '/client_secret.json');
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-php-quickstart.json
define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY)
));

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
  throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

function getClient() {
 $client = new Google_Client();
 $client->setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME);
 $client->setScopes(SCOPES);
 $client->setAuthConfigFile(CLIENT_SECRET_PATH);
 $client->setAccessType('offline');

$credentialsPath = expandHomeDirectory(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
  $accessToken = file_get_contents($credentialsPath);
} else {

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
print 'Enter verification code: ';
$authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->authenticate($authCode);

// Store the credentials to disk.
if(!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
  mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
}
file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $accessToken);
printf("Credentials saved to %s\n", $credentialsPath);
}
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
 $client->refreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
 file_put_contents($credentialsPath, $client->getAccessToken());
}
 return $client;
}

function expandHomeDirectory($path) {
$homeDirectory = getenv('HOME');
 if (empty($homeDirectory)) {
   $homeDirectory = getenv("HOMEDRIVE") . getenv("HOMEPATH");
  }
 return str_replace('~', realpath($homeDirectory), $path);
}

 $client = getClient();
 $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

 $user = 'me';
 $results = $service->users_labels->listUsersLabels($user);

if (count($results->getLabels()) == 0) {
print "No labels found.\n";
 } else {
  print "Labels:\n";
  foreach ($results->getLabels() as $label) {
  printf("- %s\n", $label->getName());
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: there is no such thing as app id with php.  Check step one https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php#prerequisites

Comment: @DalmTo. I read it and download the json file. But my problem is I don't know how can create gmail login button. how to send the data to google auth and so on.
could you explain step by step. I'm newbie to gmail login

Comment: You don't need to create a Gmail login button when you run the code it will open an authentication window in the users browser where they can authenticate your application.

Comment: @DaImTo . can you tell me how to configure it to work. 
I mean in detail
Thanks in advanced

Comment: @DaImTo. I copy and paste the step 3. also download the client_secret.json form my console . require `../autoload.php`. but it just shows me the blank page without even any error or sth else